# I tried to retrieve my data when redirecting (PYTHON/FLASK/HTML)

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to enter a word in a submit form and after I click Submit I want to be redirected to a new page where the word will be seen.

This is my python code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        word = request.form['strword']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES (%s)", [word])
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for('results', requested_word=word))
        #adding word to MySQL (I want this word displayed in my website.)
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/results/", methods=['GET'])
def results():
    i = 0
    other_list = []
    data = {'Word': 'Number of times'}
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    users = cur.execute("SELECT word, COUNT(*) FROM words GROUP BY word HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;")
    if users > 0:
        user_details = cur.fetchall()
        sorted_details = sorted(user_details, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        for user in sorted_details:
            if i < 9:
                i = i+1
                data[user[0]] = user[1]
            if i >= 9:
                other_list.append(user[1])
                data['Other'] = sum(other_list)
                i = i+1
        return render_template("results.html", data=data)
        #modifying the data from MySQL in order to be accepted for Google Charts API.
```

As you can see above, I use once **redirect(url_for('results', requested_word=word)**) and once **render_template("results.html", data=data)**.

```
<h1>You have typed the word: {{requested_word}}</h1> #not working

<h2>Data for google API: {{data}}</h2>  #working
```

I want when I enter a word and click submit to be redirected on my results page and I want to show which word have I entered.

I think that the problem comes from the fact that I use twice render_template with different arguments(codes) - once with (requested_word=word) and once with (data=data).

Comment: This platform lives from the fact that there are volunteers who are willing to sacrifice their time and use their knowledge to help others to solve their problems. In order to give these people feedback on the success of their measures, the users are given a wide variety of means. It would be nice if the questioner would use this to rate the answer and / or mark the question as answered. Even if you have received an answer, it is always possible to clarify any resulting ambiguities with comments. I hope that you understand my concerns and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You only use `render_template` once within your example. I mean, at least within the part of the code you're referring to.

The redirect calls up another URL, i.e. route, through an HTTP forwarding.
The passed parameters are embedded in the URL, which are placed in the location header of the server's response.  The browser then calls this URL automatically based on the HTTP status code. In this case 302 Found.

If you refer to another route using `url_for` and `redirect`, you should also query the parameters passed within your route to which you are forwarded.
You can do this either through [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)
or through query parameters via [`request.args`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.args). The former takes the value and passes it as an argument to your function, which maps the route. For the second solution, you ask for the value using its key from a dictionary.

From your results route you can then pass the transferred word on to your jinja2 template, as you do with the variable "data".